# Using SSJS to send single email in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Is it possible to send a single email to a Subscriber rather than a whole List using the [SSJS Send Mail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_sendAdd.htm) function?

My code is as follows, you can see we have to provide a List ID to send to.

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    // Include SSJS Core Library
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

    // retrieve all the lists in the account
    var retrievedLists = List.Retrieve();

    // Options
    var options = {
        FromName : "JSON Specified Name",
        FromAddress : "aruiz@example.com",
        Subject : "JSON Test Mail"
    };

    // Send the email to all the lists
    status = Send.Add("Existing_Email_CustKey", retrievedLists, options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only two ways to do this are to:

1. Create a Data Extension or List with just the single individual
2. Create the email as a Triggered Send Definition and initiate that way.

For 1 - there are ways to create Data Extensions and insert records via the API or SSJS Core library that can allow you to automate this process.

SSJS: [Add](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionAdd.htm)

```
var deObj = {
        "CustomerKey" : "demoDE",
        "Name" : "My Demo DE",
        "Fields" : [
          { "Name" : "Field 1", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
          { "Name" : "Field 2", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
          { "Name" : "Field 3", "FieldType" : "Date", "Ordinal" : 2 },
        ]
    };

var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
```

SSJS: [Rows.Add](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsAdd.htm)

```
var birthdayDE = DataExtension.Init("birthdayDE");
birthdayDE.Rows.Add({FirstName:"Angel",LastName:"Ruiz",EmailAddress:"aruiz@example.com",Age:24,Birthday:"11/29/1980"});
```

API: [Create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_create.htm)

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var guid = Platform.Function.GUID();
var name = "my test de - " + guid;

var de = {
    Name: name,
    CustomerKey: guid,
    Description: "Another DE added via SSJS",
    Fields: [{
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "ID",
        MaxLength: 36,
        IsPrimaryKey: true,
        IsNillable: false,
        IsRequired: true
    },
    {
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "Name",
        MaxLength: 200
    }],
    CategoryID: 101377
}

var res = prox.createItem("DataExtension", de);
```

API: [Add Data to Data Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_data_to_data_extension_object.htm) (shown in SOAP, but can be turned into WSProxy)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <soap:Header>
          <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
               <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-6421ac0b-a454-42a3-99f7-a77ace024446">
                                                      <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>     
               </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
     </soap:Header>
     <soap:Body>
          <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Options/>
                    <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                         <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                         <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                         <CustomerKey>Definition_Key</CustomerKey>
                         <Properties>
                              <Property>
                                   <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                                   <Value>johndoe@example.com</Value>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                        <Name>FirstName</Name>
                           <Value>John</Value>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                           <Name>LastName</Name>
                           <Value>Doe</Value>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                           <Name>PrimaryKey</Name>
                           <Value>PrimaryKey</Value>
                        </Property>
                    </Properties>
                 </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For 2 - If instead of SSJS you want to go via the API route, you would need to [create your TSD](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_triggered_email_interaction.htm&type=5) (also via [SSJS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_triggeredSendAdd.htm) or via [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_triggered_send_definition.htm)) inside of the UI. Then you just send an API call or SSJS function to send it to the desired recipient.

SSJS: [TSD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_triggeredSendSend.htm)

```
var triggeredSend = TriggeredSend.Init("triggeredSend");
var status = triggeredSend.Send("aruiz@example.com", {FirstName:"Angel", CouponCode:"AA1AF"});
```

REST API: [TSD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm) (There is also a [SOAP Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggeredsenddefinition.htm) that you can use if you want)

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:external_key/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "West",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I think Data Extensions would be the way to go here, can you confirm we can use them in the SSJS Send functions? I thought this was only for Lists.

Comment: Can you clarify the comment above?